# hiding controls in FCKEditor

Tags: asp.net, fckeditor

i am using FCKEditor but i dont want all the buttons that are in the toolbar area i want only some of them is there any way to hide them using css or javascript or in any other way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked into the ability to [customize the fckeditor toolbar](http://seablick.com/blog/101/customizing-fckeditor-toolbars.aspx)?

http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Configuration/Toolbar
http://developer.mindtouch.com/en/kb/Configure_the_FCKeditor_toolbar

There's FCKConfig.js which uses JSON configuration.

```
FCKConfig.ToolbarSets["Default"] = [
['Source','DocProps','-','Save','NewPage','Preview','-','Templates'],
['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteWord','-','Print','SpellCheck'],
['Undo','Redo','-','Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','RemoveFormat'],
['Form','Checkbox','Radio','TextField','Textarea','Select','Button','ImageButton','HiddenField'],
'/',
['Bold','Italic','Underline','StrikeThrough','-','Subscript','Superscript'],
['OrderedList','UnorderedList','-','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote'],
['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyFull'],
['Link','Unlink','Anchor'],
['Image','Flash','Table','Rule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak'],
'/',
['Style','FontFormat','FontName','FontSize'],
['TextColor','BGColor'],
['FitWindow','ShowBlocks','-','About'] // No comma for the last row.
] ;

FCKConfig.ToolbarSets["Basic"] = [
['Bold','Italic','-','OrderedList','UnorderedList','-','Link','Unlink','-','About']
] ;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i am searching for it from long time

Answer (score 1):

For the version 3

There is a file called config.js
There You can change the default config value... for example

```
    CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
    {
        config.entities = false;
        config.entities_greek = false;
        config.enterMode = 2;//  'br' ;
        config.shiftEnterMode = 1 ; // 'p';

        config.toolbar =
        [
            ['Source','Preview'],
            ['Bold', 'Italic',,'Underline','Strike','-','Subscript','Superscript'],
            ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink'],
            ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord'],
            ['Outdent','Indent','Blockquote'],
            ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
            ['Link','Unlink','Anchor'],
            ['Image','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','SpecialChar', 'Templates'],
            ['Format','Font','FontSize'],
            ['TextColor','BGColor'],
            ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks']                
        ];            
    };
```

### Notes

for the moment you load the ckeditor.js, the **CKEDITOR** is global, so you can change the editorConfig anywhere on your javascript this way and not only on this config.